# String Templates and Syntactic Predicates

Tags: antlr, stringtemplate

I am trying to fix my TreeWalker so that it can implement a different string template depending upon whether a bracket is found or not.

i.e. In the following formula:     x - (y - z)
Using the brackets will alter the value of the formula. Without the brackets the formula becomes x - y - z which is wrong. I am trying to use a different string template for minus and minus with a bracket. These are as follows:

```
minus(op1,op2)              ::= "$op1$ - $op2$"
minusb(op1,op2)             ::= "($op1$ - $op2$)"
```

And the TreeWalker section I am trying to use with these is below. This is only a section from a much larger TreeWalker.

```
additiveExpr
scope { bool aFlag }
@init {bool aFlag = true; }
    :   ^(PLUS
          { $additiveExpr::aFlag = false;
            $formula::mFlag = false;
          }
          op1=expression op2=expression)
        -> {$additiveExpr::aFlag}?
           plusb(op1={$op1.st},op2={$op2.st})
        -> plus(op1={$op1.st},op2={$op2.st})
    |   ^(MINUS
          {
            $additiveExpr::aFlag = false;
            $formula::mFlag = false;
          }
          op1=expression op2=expression)
        -> {$additiveExpr::aFlag}?
           minusb(op1={$op1.st},op2={$op2.st})
        -> minus(op1={$op1.st},op2={$op2.st})
```

In the above rule aFlag always returns false producing the template with no brackets. I am struggling to understand why it will not return true when there is a bracket.

I can post other parts of the Parser if that will help.

I have worked out that the conditional part is determined by syntactic predicates. I need the syntactic predicate expression to be true when the token before the additiveExpr is a bracket (lexer token OPEN '(' ). Does this need to be passed through from the Parser to the TreeWalker or can I work it out from here? This is the equivalent parser code

```
absExpr returns [string ret_type]
    :   ABS^ OPEN! additiveExpr CLOSE!
        {$ret_type = "numeric"; }
    |   additiveExpr
        {$ret_type = $additiveExpr.ret_type; }
    ;

additiveExpr returns [string ret_type]
    :   m=multiplicativeExpr ((PLUS|MINUS)^ multiplicativeExpr )*
        {$ret_type =  $m.ret_type; }
    ;
```

EDIT:

Latest parser section:

```
absExpr returns [string ret_type] 
    :   ABS^ OPEN additiveExpr CLOSE
        {$ret_type =  $additiveExpr.ret_type; }
    |   (OPEN additiveExpr CLOSE)=> OPEN additiveExpr CLOSE
        {$ret_type =  $additiveExpr.ret_type; }
    |   additiveExpr
        {$ret_type = $additiveExpr.ret_type; }
    ;
```

Comment: Tip (specifically for the ANTLR grammars I've worked on): `[]` are square brackets or just "brackets", `()` are parentheses, `{}` are curly braces or just "braces", and `<>` are angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try something like the following instead of using semantic predicates. You just have to make sure and *not* use the `!` operator in the `additiveExpr` rule in your parser grammar, or the `OPEN` and `CLOSE` tokens will not be available for your tree walker to use.

```
additiveExpr
    :   ^(PLUS OPEN op1=expression op2=expression CLOSE)
        -> plusb(op1={$op1.st},op2={$op2.st})
    |   ^(PLUS op1=expression op2=expression)
        -> plus(op1={$op1.st},op2={$op2.st})
    |   ^(MINUS OPEN op1=expression op2=expression CLOSE)
        -> minusb(op1={$op1.st},op2={$op2.st})
    |   ^(MINUS op1=expression op2=expression)
        -> minus(op1={$op1.st},op2={$op2.st})
    ;
```

---

*Previous answer:*

It's hard for me to tell exactly how you want this to work. One thing that might be a problem is this initialization:

```
scope { bool aFlag }
@init {bool aFlag = true; }
```

This declares 2 different variables with the same name `aFlag`. One of them will appear in the scope class, and the other will be a local variable in the `additiveExpr` method. You may have meant to do this instead:

```
scope { bool aFlag }
@init { $additiveExpr::aFlag = true; }
```

Comment: It might be in that area. In a simplified example I am trying to translate the following X + (Z - T). I have a string template for minus/plus and one for minus/plus with parentheses. So when my translation appears I either get parentheses round everything (MACRO(X) + (MACRO(Z) - MACRO(T))) or no parentheses MACRO(X) + MACRO(Z) - MACRO(T). I want to be able to only get parentheses when they are actually present in my original formula.

Comment: @JamesRandles I rewrote the first half of my answer. Hopefully that helps you get it working. :)

Comment: Thank you. I am much closer to the result. However, I am still struggling with the Parser part. I have tried a number of options to send the OPEN/CLOSE parentheses through to the walker but the options I have tried don't seem to work correctly. I have modified my question to include the latest section of my parser. There is clearly something wrong but I am not sure quite how to change it.